# Не могу спарсить данные с сайта

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, aiogram, aiohttp

Нужно спарсить данные автомобиля с [сайта](https://bidfax.info/), подставив в поиск его `vin`-код. И тут начинается самое интересное, на решение которого было потрачено уже почти 4 дня. Решение обязательно должно быть при использовании `aiohttp`, или `requests`/`requests_html`/`scrapy`.

`selenium` не подходит!

UPD3. (проблемы **№1** и **№2** решены, можно перейти сразу к номеру **3**)

**Проблема номер 1:**

при `GET`-запросе  я получаю сообщение о том, что нужно включить `JavaScript`. Ранее подобной проблемы при парсинге сайта не было, и мне удавалось получить `html` главной станицы сайта.
Что можно предпринять? Облазил почти все форумы - нашел только советы недопрограммистов, типа "`так включи JS и будет работать`".

Страница сайта, которую получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там есть какие-то ключи для декодирования, `slowAES.decrypt` и сам `JS`-код. Может как-то можно воспроизвести логику в `python`, чтобы это ограничение обойти?

**Проблема номер 2:**

Я смотрел в инструментах разработчика - какие передаются данные для поиска:

обычный `GET-запрос`, и токен, который генерируется из 463 символов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в общем не стал заморачиваться, чтоб переписать функцию на python, и воспользовался `js2py`, которая генерирует этот токен:

```
getToken = js2py.eval_js("""
function randomString(len) {
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62);
    var charCode = rand += rand > 9 ? (rand < 36 ? 55 : 61) : 48;
    str += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }
  return str;
}
""")

token2 = getToken(463)
print(token2)
```

Но проблема оказалось с тем, что при передаче всех этих данных - поиск не работает, на этом сайте стоит под защитой невидимая `recaptcha`.

Я пошел дальше, и проанализировал их код сайта. Нашел такую функцию, которая делает запрос напрямую к серверу (`php`-скрипт):

```
function dle_do_search(a) {
    clearInterval(dle_search_delay);
    $("#searchsuggestions").remove();
    $("body").append("<div id='searchsuggestions' style='display:none'></div>");
    $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=search", {
        query: "" + a,
        user_hash: dle_login_hash
    }, function(a) {
        $("#searchsuggestions").html(a).fadeIn().css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: "#story",
            collision: "fit flip"
        })
    });
```

В данном случае `a` - это передаваемое значение, то есть `vin`-код автомобиля.
`dle_login_hash` - я так полагаю, что это хэш сессии. Проанализировав запрос в инструментах разработчика я нашел такую переменную:

`var dle_login_hash = 'fcab770449489970ce5bb3652037c19f7f24e73';`

Я попытался воспроизвести `POST`-запрос на их сервер, но получил ошибку `403` (работало до тех пор, пока не появилась **проблема номер 1**). Возможно я упустил какой-то токен, или `sessionid` при передаче, но в функции и нет его, которую я привел выше.

Мой код:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
              "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}


data = {
    "query": "5YJ3E1EA0JF042788",
    "user_hash": "fcab770449489970ce5bb3652037c19f7f24e73"
}

async def parse_vin_carsvin():
    url = f"https://bidfax.info/engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=search"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)) as response:
            result = await response.text()
            print(result)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(parse_vin_carsvin())
```

UPD. Получилось воссоздать логику, но это только напрямую, если скопировать все из инспектора. Проверил - для корректной работы нужен `fort` и `searchkey`.

**UPD2.**
С генерацией ключа `FORT` разобрался, остался только `searchkey`.

Пока что не удалось разобраться, как он генерируется.

**UPD3.**

**Проблема номер 3:**

Вполне вероятно, что `searchkey` формируется одной из функций, которая приведена на [SlowAES](https://github.com/octopius/slowaes/tree/master/js)

Там есть такая функция `toHex(generatePrivateKey("сюда передается какой-то ключ", 16));` - вполне вероятно, она отвечает за его генерацию, но непонятно что нужно передать за ключ. Пробовал передавать и `phpsessid` и `fort` - безрезультатно. Может отвечает функция `toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b));` которая генерирует `FORT`, но я перебрал все возможные 2401 комбинаций (`7^4 = 2401`; есть значения `a`, `b`, `c`, `phpsessid`, `fort`, `1`, `2`). По факту нужно было меньше, так как оказалось что `2` это режим для декодирования `aes`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем мне так и не удалось решить проблему - я застрял на генерации ключа `searchkey` и думаю что на этом история и закончится. Пробовал уже и `selenium`  и `pyppeteer` чтоб только забирать этот ключ и уже автоматизировать процесс, но они тоже не работают должным образом.

Я написал разработчику этого сайта, чтобы узнать как они генерируют этот ключ, но мне ничего не ответили и благополучно заблокировали)) Вероятно, подумали, что я хочу увести их клиентов.

Если вы знаете, как генерируется ключ исходя из кода [SlowAES](https://github.com/octopius/slowaes/tree/master/js) - дайте мне знать об этом в комментариях.

Итог всего этого и подсказки для тех, кому это может показаться полезным:

### **1)** Чтобы спарить данные (именно этого сайта) - нужны 2 ключа: `FORT` и `searchkey`

Передаваемые ключи можно смотреть в `cookie`/`set-cookie` при запросе к сайту в инспекторе браузера.

`FORT` - ключ подтверждения, что был включен `JavaScript`;

`searchkey` - ключ, который разрешает поиск на сайте.

### **2)** JavaScript можно включить, если парсить через `requests`/`aiohttp`

Чтоб включить `JavaScript`, когда нужно спарсить данные через `aiohttp`/`requests` - вам нужно выбрать скрипт из тегов `<script>Сам скрипт</script>` и декодировать сгенерированные хэши, которые приведены на странице. Самым простым способом будет воспользоваться библиотекой `js2py` которая обрабатывает `JavaScript`-код внутри интерпретатора языка `Python` (таким образом не нужно будет писать дополнительные файлы с `*.js`, но надо будет подтянуть `var slowAES = ...` для корректной работы декодирования - в коде ниже есть пример)

### **3)** Чтоб спарсить данные - ключ можно вручную забрать из инспектора.

Чтобы парсить именно этот сайт - нужно забрать ключ `searchkey` с инспектора, и передать его вместе с `FORT`, иначе сайт будет редиректить на главную страницу.
Подобная логика может прослеживаться и на других сайтах. Сайт спустя какое-то время заново генерирует ключ `searchkey` - в этом случае процедуру нужно повторить.

Сам код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import js2py


headers = {
    'Host': 'bidfax.info',
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
              "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Language": "accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
}


token2 = js2py.eval_js("""
function randomString(len) {
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 62);
    var charCode = rand += rand > 9 ? (rand < 36 ? 55 : 61) : 48;
    str += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }
  return str;
}
""")


async def test(vin):
    url = "https://bidfax.info/"
    aes_js = "https://bidfax.info/aes.min.js"
    parse_url = f"https://bidfax.info/?do=search&subaction=search&story={vin}&token2={token2(463)}&action2=search_action"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            script = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser").find_all("script")[1].get_text()
            response = await session.get(aes_js)
            slowAES = await response.text()
            jslogic = script.split('document.cookie="')[0]
            FORT = js2py.eval_js(slowAES + jslogic + " toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b));")
            searchkey = "" # сюда нужно вставить searchkey
            session.headers.update({"Cookie": "FORT=" + FORT + "; searchkey=" + searchkey})
            res = await session.get(parse_url)
            with open("file.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                file.write(await res.text())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test("5YJ3E1EA0JF042788"))
```

Отдельное спасибо @Alexandr за подсказки на некоторых этапах!

Comment: Решил изучить selenium и взял для практики сайт, который вы указали в вопросе. Забрать  куки FORT и searchkey не составило проблемы, после загрузки страницы вызываю driver.get_cookies() и они возвращаются в массиве

Comment: @Alexandr хм, спасибо, буду знать. Меня почему-то при вводе url с vin-поиском перебрасывало на главную страницу, может что не так вводил в `selenium` (последний раз использовал его почти полтора года назад). Но я нашел более деликатное решение, и можно сказать лучшее, которое можно придумать для tg-ботов - я просто вбил в скрипте ссылку на поиск в гугле и поставил фильтрацию по сайту (`site:bidfax.info`)

Answer (score 3):

UPD

Пока разбирался с Selenium в качестве 'подопытного' взял данный сайт.

Вот мой код, который сохраняет куки в бинарник и ищет VIN машины.

```
def selenium_parser(url , driver):

  driver.get(url)
  search_input = driver.find_element_by_id('search')
  search_input.clear()
  search_input.send_keys('5YJ3E1EA0JF042788')
  submit_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
  submit_btn.click()

  time.sleep(5)

def getDataSelenium(url,parser):
       
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path='./browsers/chromedriver/chromedriver',
        seleniumwire_options=settings.SELENIUM_PROXY
    )

    try:
        cookie_name = f"{url.split('//')[-1]}_cookies"

        if os.path.exists(cookie_name):
            print('Берем куки с файла')
            for cookie in pickle.load(open(cookie_name , 'rb')):
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)

        parser(url , driver)
        

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        print('Сохраняем куки')
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open( cookie_name , 'wb'))
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

def main():
    
    getDataSelenium('https://bidfax.info', selenium_parser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Старый ответ:

Если выкинуть весь хлам то вот что получаю я:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail offer">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <a href="https://bidfax.info/tesla/model-3/10567477-tesla-model-3-range-battery-2018-gray-motor-vin-5yj3e1ea0jf042788.html">
                    <img class="xfieldimage skrin" src="/uploads/posts/2021-10/08/tesla-model-3-2018-5yj3e1ea0jf042788-img1.jpg" alt="">
                    
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="price"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><span class="prices" id="prices-10567477">26575</span></div>
            
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="https://bidfax.info/tesla/model-3/10567477-tesla-model-3-range-battery-2018-gray-motor-vin-5yj3e1ea0jf042788.html"><h2>Tesla Model 3 Range Battery 2018 Gray MOTOR  vin: 5YJ3E1EA0JF042788</h2></a>
                
                <p class="short-storyup">Аукцион: <span class="iaai">&nbsp;IAAI&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/templates/ru/dleimages/onapproval2.png" alt="На утверждении" title="На утверждении" style="margin-top:-4px"></p>
                <p class="short-story">Номер лота:&nbsp;<span class="blackfont">31321550</span></p>
                <p class="short-story2">Состояние:&nbsp;<span class="blackfont">Run and Drive</span></p>
                <p class="short-story">Повреждение:&nbsp;<span class="blackfont">Flood</span></p>
                <p class="short-story2">Пробег:&nbsp;<span class="blackfont">9360&nbsp;миль&nbsp;(Actual)</span></p>
                <p class="short-story">Дата продажи:&nbsp;<span class="blackfont">07.10.2021</span></p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <a href="https://bidfax.info/tesla/model-3/10567477-tesla-model-3-range-battery-2018-gray-motor-vin-5yj3e1ea0jf042788.html" class="btn btn-default btn-more pull-right" role="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        
    </div>
                </div>
```

Сделал обычным requests. Все данные для запроса перехватил через burpsuite и добавил в запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

адрес запроса выглядит примерно так:

```
https://bidfax.info/?do=search&subaction=search&story=5YJ3E1EA0JF042788&token2=03AGdBq27XAie48A7sAG9gqugwLVvp9Ve5m9DpwyvhRviVHQy_iCZXdl-Rf2UH-2oFGpINU7ZMHMOZCXENBIwwgzEmy6w1kGV8qrGt-sOG0pDRYWYJTSDq7H1VvA7ZGMPmIu37AI3JebUBAquXdU-H090ubYA3j6JZ-M52YWKTWM1mG6rX-w1TkgDottqIf5P03mlM5nOoU_9ft0D6usirRDNSr8JFK8aEpYvba7fdPwGiIZg-B8H6OlZpTXxJyvsHXCkWUpvQXgsq4QIXmCKXiVoMUgvBvFWE_pgeqSIpFIaddHK50gqPFEcWLFrxbyUOiJWKA_Sjkay8wJqfLbo3b8kB1SIhG2XdjdknRnADqB32j0qmA2ZSoynEW2s9sNmz76VUI861RbOOyhDi_Q4HgJrcNeEf6N3qWYGPXbjXt2uSA547u__tWdwGy93WeGRihRZEntvemDQVzFOwHe1v4DotsQ&action2=search_action
```

Изначальные заголовки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может неправильно понял вопрос, не знаю, если что пишите

UPD:
Удалил куки с браузера и через Burpsuite посмотрел этапы прохождения капчи и соедниения для главной страницы. И там тоже возвращается, что нужно включить js, просто видимо это первый этап
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю вам стоит изучить последовательность этих запросов и попытаться их воспроизвести:

1. Первый шаг голый запрос без кук, получаем script и ссылка на aes.js
2. Загружаем этот aes.js и видимо исполняем скрипт

   var a=toNumbers("b0bd65ce35df0ebd05a1c3fa2647308f"),
   b=toNumbers("a89b6850a385bcf6f3a8f3514e1b16a4"),
   c=toNumbers("f4f9556a8771fea9632da685e849382b");
   document.cookie="FORT="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";
   expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
   location.href="https://bidfax.info/?fortespro_42=1";

(это кусок кода из того, что вам возвращается с сообщение включите js, данное сообщение будет отображаться в браузере и не будет запущен код js, который инициирует дальнейшие действияя)

В этом коде на фронте формируется  "FORT"

3. Когда делаем третий запрос у нас уже есть в куках FORT
4. на этом шаге видно, как мы отсылаем FORT и получаем PHPSSESID(тут мы уже получаем страницу, которую можно парсить, но дальше есть еще куча всего)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечный вывод: надо скопировать js код себе, так как он статичен, с его помощью и формировать "FORT" самому и отдавать его обратно в python для запросов

Comment: провел эксперемент:
сделал список из vin кодов, и запускаю запрос меняя в ссылке только часть 'story=5YJ3E1EA0JF042788' и возвращает страницы

Comment: Да, это в целом то что мне и нужно. Но думаю, что со временем, (например минут 30, или при открытии новой сессии) `phpssesid` может изменится (не уверен). Как получить непосредственно его в коде, если доступ изначально будет закрыт "Проблема номер 1"?

Comment: А за подсказку  по `Burpsuite` - спасибо, буду знать на будущее)

Comment: ради эксперемента выкинул из кук phpsessid и сработало отлично без него. Вроде [как написано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370951/what-is-phpsessid) если его не передавать php сам его генерит и все, ну а requests видимо сам уже управляет им

Comment: А откуда тогда взялся `searchkey`? Без него тоже работает? Посмотрел уже - он непосредственно из куков

Comment: ну видимо выдается сервером при первом подключении, вы можете увидеть его в куках до того, как начали поиск чего либо, при первой загрузке главной страницы, добавил изображение в ответ

Comment: Окей, спасибо - сейчас буду пробовать воссоздать у себя через комп

Comment: Да, получилось воссоздать логику - но это только напрямую, если скопировать все из инспектора. Проверил - для корректной работы нужен `fort` и `searchkey`. И главный вопрос - как тогда в скрипте их получить перед тем, как делать запрос на поиск vin? Этому мешает проблема №1. Если сделать один запрос, к примеру, на главную страницу - в куках будет пусто, а в `text()` будет по прежнему ошибка с `JS`. Получается нужно 2 запроса, но 1 не отдает то, что нужно (`searhkey` и `fort`). В `response.cookies` пусто `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`

Comment: Точнее запрос нужен не на главную страницу, а на поиск, чтоб получить `searchkey` и `fort`, но там по прежнему ограничение с `JS`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130454/discussion-between-alexandr-and-denrudi).

Comment: изучил подробнее и обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Еще один дополнительный совет, как видно из изображения данная кука формируется на 15 лет, думаю не стоит сильно парится, а searchkey могу предположить формируется именно на 'FORT'(надо проверить), и меняться не будет пока FORT  не поменяется, хоть searchkey и пересоздается каждый раз он всегда у меня одинаковый

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
Доказательство по поводу searchkey

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Доберусь вечером до компьютера и буду разбираться

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "searchkey могу предположить формируется именно на 'FORT'"?  С генерацией `FORT` уже разобрался и на всякий сформировал его в `python`-коде, осталось только разобраться с `searchkey`

Comment: Я имел ввиду , что сервер получает fort и phpsessid и может на основе одной из этих кук генерировать ответ с searchkey. Но searchkey формируется на бэке, так что это только догадки. Но у меня в течении одной сессии и не удаляя FORT она не менялась

Comment: На последнем скрине видно, что мы отправляем запрос через поиск без нее, и нам сервер ее возвращает через set cookie

Comment: Да, но это только через программу burpsuite. В реальности через python-код, когда делаю поиск - в данный момент получаю ошибку о том  что `reCAPTCHA: недопустимый домен для ключа сайта` и меня перебрасывает на главную страницу сайта. Думаю решение как раз за тем, чтобы авторизоваться через recaptcha, и только тогда будет на беке сформирован searchkey (это только предположение) Я в общем-то пытался разобраться с кодом для recaptcha, но он обфусцирован и трудно читаем

Comment: Походу так и есть, потому что, исходя из `js`-кода `if(get_cookie('searchkey') || has_capcha_ansver){...` если нет `searchkey` то пойдет условие для формирования `has_capcha_ansver`, а она `true` и уже вызывает функцию формирования капчи